# Problems using poly kernel in GridSearchCV and SVM classifier

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to do a grid search using a SVM classifier.

Consider my `data` and `target` that have been parsed from file and input to numpy arrays.

I then preprocess them.

```
# Transform the data to have zero mean and unit variance.
zeroMeanUnitVarianceScaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(data)
zeroMeanUnitVarianceScaler.transform(data)
scaledData = data

# Transform the target to have range [-1, 1].
scaledTarget = np.empty([161L,], dtype=int)
for i in range(len(target)):
    if(target[i] == 'Malignant'):
        scaledTarget[i] = 1
    if(target[i] == 'Benign'):
        scaledTarget[i] = -1
```

I now try to set up my grid and fit the scaled data to targets.

```
# Generate parameters for parameter grid.
CValues = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
GammaValues = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)
kernelValues = ('poly', 'sigmoid')
# kernelValues = ('linear', 'rbf', 'sigmoid')
degreeValues = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
coef0Values = np.logspace(-3, 3, 7)

# Generate the parameter grid.
paramGrid = dict(C=CValues, gamma=GammaValues, kernel=kernelValues, 
coef0=coef0Values)

# Create and train a SVM classifier using the parameter grid and with 
stratified shuffle split.
stratifiedShuffleSplit = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 10, test_size = 
0.25, train_size = None, random_state = 0)
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm.SVC(), param_grid=paramGrid, 
cv=stratifiedShuffleSplit, n_jobs=1) 
clf.fit(scaledData, scaledTarget)
```

If I uncomment the line `kernelValues = ('linear', 'rbf', 'sigmoid')`, then the code runs in approximately 50 seconds on my 16 GB i7-4950 3.6 GHz machine running windows 10.
However, if I try to run the code as is with `'poly'` as a possible kernel value, then the code hangs forever. For example, I ran it yesterday overnight and it did not return anything when I got back in the office today.

Interestingly enough, if I try to create a SVM classifier with a poly kernel, it returns a result immediately

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='poly',degree=2)
clf.fit(data, target)
```

It hangs up when I do the above code. I have not tried other cv methods to see if that changes anything.

Is this a bug in sci-kit learn? Am I doing things properly? On a side note, is my method of doing gridsearch/cross validation using GridSearchCV and StratifiedShuffleSplit sensible? It seems to me the most brute force (i.e. time consuming) but robust method.

Thank you!

Comment: It works fine on my computer! Although, I am using sklearn v17! I have suggestion for you to track the issue. reduce the size of your gridsearch first  so you can search on a smaller gridparameters. for instance CValues = np.logspace(-3, 3, 2), GammaValues = np.logspace(-3, 3, 2), degreeValues = np.array([0, 1, 2]),  and coef0Values = np.logspace(-3, 3, 2). Then turn on the verbos in gridsearchcv. for instance verbose=1000 and see where your code stalls. NOTE that you need to reduce the search domain as I mentioned. Otherwise your computer my hang as it would try to write the param search out.

Comment: Without the actual data, its hard to say if its a bug or not.

Comment: @MhFarahani Thanks, I will try the verbose output and update once I figure something out. It is also nice to know that it works on your computer  as that narrows the possibility of issues. I will also try it with one of the embedded data sets.